# Removing text and keep digits in panda

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe similar to this:

[image]

I want to remove text and keep digits only from each column in that dataframe.

The expected output something like this:

[image]

So far I have tried this:

```
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd
URL = 'https://xxxxx.com'
req = requests.get(URL,auth=('xxx', 'xxx') )
text_data= req.text
json_dict= json.loads(text_data)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(json_dict["measurements"])
cols_to_keep =['source','battery','c8y_TemperatureMeasurement','time','c8y_DistanceMeasurement']
df_final = df[cols_to_keep]
df_final = df_final.rename(columns={'c8y_TemperatureMeasurement': 'Temperature Or T','c8y_DistanceMeasurement':'Distance'})
for col in df_final:
 df_final[col] = [''.join(re.findall("\d*\.?\d+", item)) for item in df_final[col]]
```

Comment: Post code and data. Do NOT post images of such.

Comment: And add what you tried

Comment: Dear @James and  Clément, as per your kind request , I have attached the code and data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is missing *import pandas as pd* and the data cannot be accessed, because it requires credentials.

You can use [pandas.DataFrame.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html):

Example data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['abc123abc', 'def456678'], 'b':['123a', 'b456']})
```

Dataframe:

```
    a           b
0   abc123abc   123a
1   def456678   b456
```

[^0-9.] replaces all non-digit characters.

```
df.replace('[^0-9.]', '', regex=True)
```

Output:

```
    a       b
0   123     123
1   456678  456
```

---

Edit:
The problem here is actually about nested JSON and not about replacing values in a dataframe. The reason the statement above does not work is because the data is saved as dicts in in the dataframe. But since the above mentioned solution is generally correct, it won't edit it out.

Revised Answer:

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import requests
import pandas as pd

URL = 'https://wastemanagement.post-iot.lu/measurement/measurements?source=83512& pageSize=1000000000&dateFrom=2019-10-26&dateTo=2019-10-28'
req = requests.get(URL,auth=('xxxx', 'xxxx') )
text_data= req.text
json_dict= json.loads(text_data)
df= json_normalize(json_dict['measurements'])
df = df_final.rename(columns={'source.id': 'source', 'battery.percent.value': 'battery', 'c8y_TemperatureMeasurement.T.value': 'Temperature Or T','c8y_DistanceMeasurement.distance.value':'Distance'})
cols_to_keep =['source' ,'battery', 'Temperature Or T', 'time', 'Distance']
df_final = df[cols_to_keep]
```

Output:

```
    source  battery Temperature Or T    time                        Distance
0   83512   98.0    NaN                 2019-10-26T00:00:06.494Z    NaN
1   83512   NaN     23.0                2019-10-26T00:00:06.538Z    NaN
2   83512   NaN     NaN                 2019-10-26T00:00:06.577Z    21.0
3   83512   98.0    NaN                 2019-10-26T00:30:06.702Z    NaN
4   83512   NaN     23.0                2019-10-26T00:30:06.743Z    NaN
```

Comment: Based on your actual data I revised my answer. Please remove your credentials and post the json sample in your answer for future visits. I don't exactly know what the site is, but you don't want your credentials to be public.